# How to use Win32API SendMessage to change Save Dialog File Location?

Tags: winapi, sendmessage, savefiledialog

I am writing a program that automates saving data to a specific location, based on the common Save/Save As dialog.

[image]

There are two attacking approaches. Both approaches require monitoring handles for messages under Spyxx (so essentially we are trying to replicate the SendMessage)

The **first** approach to set the **File Name** with target path, using Win32 SendMessage API. The HWnd in this case is the `Edit` field next to the File name.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);

SendMessage(HWnd, (int)WindowMessage.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, @"Address: %UserProfile%\Desktop\Target.txt");
```

The problem with this approach is that, it does not always set the text under Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 (I do have better luck with Windows 10). I tried to set some waiting time, but no matter how long I wait, it doesn't seem to matter (besides SendMessage is synchronous operation, so text should be set, or not set at all)

The **second** approach is to set the **Location** at the top of the dialog box. Again, we are using SendMessage to accomplish this, and HWnd in this case, references the `ToolbarWindow32` object, which is the child of `Breadcrumb Parent` object.

```
SendMessage(HWnd, (int)WindowMessage.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, @"Address: %UserProfile%\Desktop");
```

or

```
SendMessage(HWnd, (int)WindowMessage.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, @"Address: Desktop"); // replicated message found on Spyxx
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not seem to work (i.e. I can send the message, but Dialog doesn't change its location), and I have yet to figure out what steps I am missing.

My question, how do you use Win32 API to interact with the 3rd party app's Save As dialog, so that you can guarantee saving the file in the desired location? Much appreciated and thanks for reading!

Comment: Does UI Automation help? Also what are you trying to "attack"?

Comment: Why are you marshaling as `LPStr`? That is an 8bit ANSI string. Try using `LPWStr` instead, as system native dialogs are likely to be using Unicode windows. Like andlabs said, UI Automation would be better than raw window messages. But if that does not work, you might have to resort to injecting a DLL into the 3rd party process and have it hook `CoCreateInstance()` with a detour that implements a COM delegate to wrap `IFileSaveDialog` and override its `Show()` method with custom logic, then you can do whatever you want when `Show()` is called without actually showing the real dialog.

Comment: @andlabs Not trying to hack the app. Just want to automate the process by saving a few mouse clicks. That's all, and it is more fun to write the code yourself instead of relying on existing UI Automation

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you know a good tutorial for the DLL injection as well as `CoCreateInstance`? Problem with DLL injection is that I don't even know which dll to inject. IDA Pro doesn't pin point the exact function in which DLL file containing the File Save routine

Comment: The dialog you are trying to automate is not implemented in a DLL function. It is implemented as a COM object. You could inject *your own* DLL (there are many techniques for doing that) containing a custom class that implements the `IFileSaveDialog` interface. Once injected, your DLL can intercept the native `Ole32.CoCreateInstance()` function. When the app calls `CoCreateInstance()` requesting an `IFileSaveDialog` object, your function would be called instead, returning an instance of your class. The app won't know the difference since all it sees is the interface...

Comment: ... Your class can simply return success codes for all of the `IFileSaveDialog` methods without doing anything, and then have its `GetResult()` method return an `IShellItem` object that refers to the desired file path.

Comment: If you want to hook only certain Save dialogs and not others, your `CoCreateInstance()` hook can call the native `Ole32.CoCreateInstance()` function first to get the system's default `IFileSaveDialog` object and wrap it inside your class instance, delegating all of your `IFileSaveDialog` methods to the native object's methods and analyzing the values being assigned. When your `Show()` and `GetResult()` methods are called, you can decide whether to call the native object's methods or return simulated values, based on the configuration values that the app assigned.

Comment: I'd use UI Automation and get the job done, but if you'd rather hack away like this, so be it.